# How do I make NPC follow me in Gamemaker Studio 1.4

Tags: game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-1.4

I've been trying to get an NPC, in my case a zombie, to follow me in my game of course to no avail. I'm using the following script for my character to move

```
if(keyboard_check(vk_left)){
    sprite_index = spr_player;
    x -= 4;
}

if(keyboard_check(vk_right)){
    sprite_index = spr_player;
    x+= 4;
}

if(keyboard_check(vk_down)){
    sprite_index = spr_player;
    y += 4;
}
```

The name of the NPC object is (obj_zombie).

Comment: This may get better answers here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the simple system you are using to move player object you may just make another object follow to another object (object to object) using [move_towards_point(x,y,speed);](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/movement/move_towards_point.html) function in **step event** of the object zombie in this way:

```
move_towards_point(obj_Player.x, obj_Player.y,5);
```

Where obj_Player is of course the name of you player object, which i dont know which is it so i just put obj_Player, you should change it to match yours.

To change the sprite to the direction its moving you can just check the [direction](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/movement/direction.html) the object is going and depending of then the sprite may change or the scale of the sprite may change.

```
if (direction > 90) and (direction < 270) {
   // left direction
} else {
   // right direction
}
```

> Note: Links over some text in this answer redirect you to game maker
>   studio reference code documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As Jr Jimnz said, in this case it's better if you use move_towards_point(x,y,speed), personally, that's the system i use in some cases, too!
or else, you could use the sign function:

```
 if (instance_exists(//insert your player object here)) {
 x += sign(//player object.x - x);
 y += sign(//player object.y - y);}
```

but the sign system is not-so convenient.

sorry for my bad english.